# Magento Search Order by Search Key word in name

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I'm trying to order the search results based on the product name. For example
if we search using word "Cover Plate" the products which has cover plate in its name should show first.

I have already tried methods like adding 
`<input type="hidden" name="order" value="name"/>` in  form.mini.phtml.

And tried editing `Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php` 
tried editing `/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php` etc...

I think even if we use  its ordering the results. In above example the search is finding all the product with name cover plates and in its attributes and then ordering the those results based on name. So if there is a product name that starts with letter 'A' it will be listed first. Or may be its showing product which has search key word in its description first. My requirement is to show the product with name cover plate first. How can i do that. Which page i need to edit to accomplish this.

EDIT : Magento is giving importance to description while listing the products. Is there a way so that products with searched name can be listed first instead of description. Currently if there are matching words in the description then it is shown first.